# Get difference between grouped values in tall dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, diff

I have a data set set up like the example below:

```
Name     df Value
A         1   .5
A         2    2
A         3    3
B         1    1
B         2    .5
```

I would like to get the difference between the values unitil the Name column changes then I would like it to stop and start getting the new differences. Like below:

```
Name     df Value   Diff
A         1   .5      NA
A         2    2      1.5
A         3    3      2.5
B         1    1       NA
B         2    .5     -.5
```

Is there any way I can do this? I have tried making the data set into wide format but I cannot figure out a way to make that work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be to do a group by `diff`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Name) %>%
    mutate(Diff = c(NA, cumsum(diff(Value))))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   Name [2]
#  Name     df Value  Diff
#  <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A         1   0.5  NA  
#2 A         2   2     1.5
#3 A         3   3     2.5
#4 B         1   1    NA  
#5 B         2   0.5  -0.5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), df = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), Value = c(0.5, 2, 3, 1, 0.5)), 
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 2):

*@akrun* answer is the way to go, but just as a riddle, this works too:

```r
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  mutate(Diff = cumsum(Value - lag(Value, default = Value[1])))
```

```r
# # A tibble: 5 x 4
# # Groups:   Name [2]
#   Name     df Value  Diff
#   <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A         1   0.5   0  
# 2 A         2   2     1.5
# 3 A         3   3     2.5
# 4 B         1   1     0  
# 5 B         2   0.5  -0.5
```